# Placing Text on Grid Layout Border Lines - React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

Bit of an interesting one here. I'm trying to make a React/Tailwinds web app for guitar music theory. I want to create something that looks similar to the chart below. I decided to go with a grid and all is good except the notes are in the middle of the cells and I want them to be on the lines as is shown in the image. Was curious if anyone here had any good approaches. Thanks a ton in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use negative margins to position the circles. e.g. `-mt-8`